Do executables in different containers share shared objects that are define in the same common image layer?
I am investigating the memory impact of containerising two processes that depend on the same shared object. My main question is whether the shared object will be loaded in memory twice or not.
This question has been asked before, but the answers were not complete and contradicting with my experiments. I will cite what I already encountered:
Loading of shared libraries and RAM usage --> Use -fPIC for your .so
Do docker containers share RAM for files memory mapped from the same layer but a different image? --> Yes, but depends on your setup. You can prove it but checking the device and inode id of the loaded shared object. No indication of what setup to use.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35863608/shared-library-in-containers --> Yes, depends on your storage driver. aufs, overlay or overlay2 storage drivers support this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63145223/about-loading-dynamic-library-in-container --> Each container is its own execution unit. No sharing occurs. Contradicting with the previous.
I used the following setup:

base layer --> Contains the OS and two shared objects (G and S - Precompiled using -fPIC)
dependsOnG layer --> Starts from base, contains the executable which
depends only on G (Precompiled)
dependsOnGandS layer --> Starts from base, contains the
executable that depends both on G and S (Precompiled)

Storage driver: Overlay
Below you can see the information from grep glib /proc/PID/maps. The PIDs are the processes of the executables inside the container.
| /proc/17/maps:7efd3b630000-7efd41980000 | r-xp | 00000000 | 00:a2             | 16802420 | /app/libglib.so |
| /proc/17/maps:7efd41980000-7efd41b7f000 | ---p | 06350000 | 00:a2             | 16802420 | /app/libglib.so |
| /proc/17/maps:7efd41b7f000-7efd41b80000 | r--p | 0634f000 | 00:a2             | 16802420 | /app/libglib.so |
| /proc/17/maps:7efd41b80000-7efd41b81000 | rw-p | 06350000 | 00:a2             | 16802420 | /app/libglib.so |

| /proc/39/maps:7fca97208000-7fca9d558000 | r-xp | 00000000 | 00:bb             | 16802420 | /app/libglib.so |
| /proc/39/maps:7fca9d558000-7fca9d757000 | ---p | 06350000 | 00:bb             | 16802420 | /app/libglib.so |
| /proc/39/maps:7fca9d757000-7fca9d758000 | r--p | 0634f000 | 00:bb             | 16802420 | /app/libglib.so |
| /proc/39/maps:7fca9d758000-7fca9d759000 | rw-p | 06350000 | 00:bb             | 16802420 | /app/libglib.so |

If I interpret the result correctly, the two processes view completely different files (the device id is different), thus, the shared object will be loaded twice in memory (seems consistent with what I see with the free command).
According to the information I found online this shouldn't happen.
I have the following questions:

Should the shared object be loaded only once?
Does the overlay storage driver support this functionality?
Should I be constructing my images/containers in a different way? (I did the same experiments using volumes instead of common layers and indeed the files were identical, however, that's not quite what I want)

Thanks in advance!

I just happened to came across this statement as I was checking out the btrfs storage driver: Btrfs doesn't support page cache sharing. This means that each process accessing the same file copies the file into the Docker host's memory. I wonder if that's what you are asking about, and if so, the answer seems to be "it depends".

Support for composefs is currently being added to Podman. The integration is not yet quite production-ready as I see there are bugs being fixed during the last weeks (July 2024).
Support for composefs will hopefully bring these features when running rootful podman:

Shared disk space for identical files
Shared page cache for identical files

(The identical files do not need to belong to the same layer)
For an introduction to composefs, see this presentation (video + slides)
https://fosdem.org/2024/schedule/event/fosdem-2024-3250-composefs-and-containers/
There is ongoing development for starting to use composefs in image-based operating system (e.g. Fedora Silverblue, Fedora CoreOS). In the future it might even be possible to get sharing of disk space and page cache for identical files between the host and the containers.

There's two reasons you are seeing confusion on this topic:

Docker is configurable. So if you give a definitive "yes" or "no" someone will almost certainly find a plugin or obscure configuration to prove you wrong.
Some people have misunderstood containers to be closer to virtual machines and believe they are more isolated than they are in practice.

The simple answer is that, by default, docker will share memory between containers for the same file when it comes from the same layer.  Changing the sorage driver may cause it to do otherwise (as pointed out here).


If I interpret the result correctly, the two processes view completely different files (the device id is different)

No that’s not true.  Hint: It’s quite unlikely that two identical files will end up with the same inode number on two different file systems by chance.
The behaviour you are now seeing is documented under overlay:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/overlayfs.html#inode-properties

In the special case of all overlay layers on the same underlying filesystem, all objects will report an st_dev from the overlay filesystem and st_ino from the underlying filesystem. This will make the overlay mount more compliant with filesystem scanners and overlay objects will be distinguishable from the corresponding objects in the original filesystem.

I don’t know how/when this changed after Stephen Kitt’s answer. I know I checked the results at the time.
Since the layers of your docker image and the writable layer are all on the same filesystem then it follows that you would expect a different device (st_dev), even if the same underlying filesystem object has been mapped only once. That’s because each container has its own writable layer and so Docker will mount a new overlay for each one.
But the overlay simply passes through to unmodified files on the underlying filesystem.
Documentation
https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/#the-image-layers

The image layer directories contain the files unique to that layer as well as hard links to the data shared with lower layers. This allows for efficient use of disk space.

I've not checked the results, but since the image is composited via hard links, you should be able to investigate the contents of the image layers and confirm they are the same files with a simple stat <file> command.
So when using overlay, the file content will be the same file stored in the same place on disk and not a copy. This way the disk cache will only need to load it once.

Thanks for the extensive reply. The experiment I run involves monitoring the memory with free -m -s 2 and running the two processes first on the host os and then on separate containers, which have the same base layer with the .so. When running in the host OS, the free memory is decreased by the amount of the shared library only once, whereas in containers it's decreased twice. And I see an equivalent increase in the cache. I realized that the container management tool is podman, not docker (sorry for the incorrect tag). What configuration options should I check? The storage driver is Overlay.

I think the question is going to need further details. Have you investigated the way podman composites its images on disk? IE have you checked files are hard linked between layers as docker does? Also what’s you lt host filesystem? https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/btrfs-driver/

I am quite new to this, but these are the findings. When inspecting the /var/lib/containers/**/overlay, I see the folder "l" with all the simlinks to the individual layers. Also, the driver is overlay (according to the documentation: In Docker, there were options to use overlay or overlay2 drivers, but Podman treats these as interchangeable to mean overlay2) and the Backing Filesystem is xfs (same in host). I expected with this setup that page caching is supported. Is it possible that the free command gives misleading results (although I use the same in my non-container setup)?

@A.G This one keeps throwing me surprises. I've just worked through some basic checks and it seems the docker documentation mentioning hard links is wrong. It doesn't hard-link the files but sets up a multi-layer overlay. I also note that docker claims that cache is shared: https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/#page-caching I've not successfully found a reason for yours seeing otherwise.
